# PHP How to fill up variable with range() and extra numbers

Tags: php, arrays, range

I need to fill up an variable with *range* and some extra numbers.  So my variable should have numbers `101-167, `201-245` + `255`. For one range is easy, but can't figure out to add extra numbers:

```
$i = range(101,167) ??
```

Then I also have a case that I need to remove few numbers  **301-351**, but take out **329** and **340**.   Do I just make several ranges like 301-218, 330-339, 341-351? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_merge()` to concatenate multiple arrays.

```
$multi_ranges = array_merge(range(101, 167), range(201, 245), [255]);
```

You can use `array_diff()` to remove a list of values from the range:

```
$range_without = array_diff(range(301, 351), [329, 340]);
```

You can combine these arbitrarily.

```
$ranges = array_merge(
    range(101, 167), 
    range(201, 245), 
    [255], 
    array_diff(range(301, 351), [329, 340])
);
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks @Barmar , is it possible to remove a few elements?

Comment: Not that I can think of, just split up the ranges as you suggested.

Comment: Good, thanks will do that then.  `$i = array_merge(range(301, 339), range(330, 339), range(341, 351))`

Comment: You can use array_diff to remove values.

Comment: @Daniels118 Good idea. I've updated the answer to show an example.